# Decimal to hexadecimal upto two bytes in Excel

Tags: excel, hex

DEC2HEX converts a number into default number of bytes (in my case MS Office Standard 10 -upto 5 bytes), for example:

dec2hex(NUMBER) = FFFFFFFB8A.

Is there a way to trim it to 2 bytes? = ABCD.

`NUMBER` is a decimal integer.

Comment: -1142 decimal would be FB8A hexadecimal using two's complement.  So I'm unsure how you get ABCD?

Comment: ABCD is just an example....not related with hex..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=DEC2HEX(MOD(-1142,HEX2DEC(10000)),4)`

or

`=DEC2HEX(MOD(-1142,65536),4)`

or

`=RIGHT(DEC2HEX(-1142,4),4)`

Comment: works ! but what about 0, it gives 0 for 0, it should give 0000.Updated Qs.

Comment: @Raulp Updated answer - dec2hex takes an optional argument specifying the minimum number of places.